# Why use a namespace and pollute the code with "this"

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a large JavaScript project and am thinking about encapsulating it in a namespace to avoid the global scope. From what I have read, it is better to not pollute the global scope. When trying to do this, my code becomes littered with "this" everywhere I look. Why would I want to do this, when I could just make sure my global variables have unique names?

```
$m.Timers.Layer = {
    chunk: 3,
    c: null,
    total: null,
    update: function() {
        this.c = 0;
        this.total = $m.db.length;
        setTimeout(this.op1.bind(this), 0);
    },
    op1: function() {
        var end = this.c + this.chunk;
        if (end > this.total) { end = this.total }

        for (this.c; this.c < end; this.c++) {
            alert(this.c);
        }

        if (this.c != this.total) { setTimeout(this.op1.bind(this), 0) }
    }
};
```

It is so much harder to understand like 'this', no pun intended!

**EDIT:** This question originally used the word Closure and has be changed to Namespace.

Comment: You don't have any closures in that code example.

Comment: "when I could just make sure my global variables have unique names" — Then you have to track variable names across every script (including third party scripts), which is hard.

Comment: This code doesn't have much to do with closures. The point of writing it like this is allowing the user to create many layers that operate independently of one another by encapsulating the state of each layer and the functions that work with that state.

Comment: Every third party script I'm using is all Closured up though, lol... i.e. google, openlayers, jquery...

Comment: @Quentin: *"You don't have any closures in that code example."* Sure he does. I count two.

Comment: @scuzzlebuzzle: It seems you don't have the correct idea of what a closure is. I suggest reading more on the subject.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are correct. I have updated the question to the word Namespace. Thanks

Comment: Well, if you don't like *this*, why not use closures?

Answer (score 2):

In the example you give, the purpose of using `this` is to avoid having to write `$m.Timers.Layer` everywhere.

If someone calls the function assigned to `$m.Timers.Layer.update` via that property, within that call, `this` refers to `$m.Timers.Layer`, and so `this.c` refers to `$m.Timers.Layer.c`.

Perhaps more importantly, if someone does this:

```
var l = $m.Timers.Layer;
l.update(/*...*/);
```

...within the call, `this` still refers to `$m.Timers.Layer`, and so `this.c` *still* refers to `$m.Timers.Layer.c`.

---

Note, though, that **closures** and **`this`** have very little to do with one another. The purpose of a closure is to close over data in scope where it's defined. `this` is effectively an argument in a function call. In fact, it's fairly common to use closures to *avoid* using `this` (by using a variable referencing the desired object instead).

Further reading (on my blog):

- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Comment: I'm sorry I was mistaken. I don't completely understand closures, the correct word I was looking for was Namespace. Thanks

Comment: @scuzzlebuzzle: Fundamentally, the answer doesn't change (other than the bit below the break). Using `this` is a shorthand, and more reliable, way to refer to `$m.Timers.Layer`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid *this*, use closures along the lines

```
var $m = {Layer:{}};

(function(exports) {

    var c = null;
    var total = null;

    function update() {
        c = 0;
        total = db.length;
        ...
    }

    exports.update = update;
})($m.Layer);
```